# SQL detect sequences of the same character?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

I have a table filled with items which have IDs of characters.

**Example**:

```
"TGHZN"
"FVGHR"
"OLTVD"
"EERFV" -- invalid because of EE (sequence of the same character)
"EFEDC"
"DFFFB" -- invalid because of FFF
```

How can I select all rows with invalid IDs?

A invalid ID is defined by a sequence of the equal characters (e.g. `AA`) within the ID.

I've tried it with RegEx without success: `SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID LIKE '%(.)\1+%'`

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to do with SQL Server because SQL Server does not support regular expressions (calling the mild enhancements to 'LIKE' "regular expressions" is serious marketing-overspeak).

Assuming your ids have a length of 5, you can try something like this:

```
where (id like '%' + substring(id, 1, 1) + substring(id, 1, 1) + '%') or
      (id like '%' + substring(id, 2, 1) + substring(id, 2, 1) + '%') or
      (id like '%' + substring(id, 3, 1) + substring(id, 3, 1) + '%') or
      (id like '%' + substring(id, 4, 1) + substring(id, 4, 1) + '%')
```

SQL Server does not (out-of-the-box) support regular expressions.

Actually, the `replicate()` function would make the logic a tad clearer:

```
where (id like '%' + replicate(substring(id, 1, 1), 2) + '%') or
      (id like '%' + replicate(substring(id, 2, 1), 2) + '%') or
      (id like '%' + replicate(substring(id, 3, 1), 2) + '%') or
      (id like '%' + replicate(substring(id, 4, 1), 2) + '%')
```

Comment: Ok with 480k rep i assume this is "the" solution ... but why is my RegEx approch not possible? I thought with like it should work somehow

Comment: @GodofSource SQL Server only supports minimal regex like expressions. You can't use it's full functionality. Basically stuff like [0-9], use of % as wildcard and ^ for negation or starting, among a few other things, but you aren't going to solve complex issues that you could with regex in other languages. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx

Comment: @GodofSource . . . Oh, that is simple.  SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option  (no limit on the length of ID)

```
Select Distinct A.ID 
From   YourTable A
Join  (Select Top 26 Patt=Replicate(Char(64+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)),2) From master..spt_values ) B
  on   CharIndex(B.Patt,A.ID)>0
```

Comment: This version assumes that the characters are ASCII capital letters.  It gets a bit more cumbersome if any letters are included . . . including national character sets.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are correct, I did not consider national character sets, but regarding capital letters, only if your collation is set to CS. A simple fix would be to change TOP 26 to TOP 255 and remove the 64+

Answer (score -1):

Remove the '+' from the expression you have written. following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID LIKE '%(.)\1%'
```

Comment: Down-voted for using syntax that does not exist in SQL Server and not doing the minimal testing e.g. `select 1 where 'AAAAA' LIKE '%(.)\1%`

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'FOO' LIKE '%(.)\1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ID` returns `0`